# jqplot axis short numbers as ticks values

Tags: jqplot

I have an issue with a jqplot graph. The issue is that ticks numbers are overlapped:

[image]

I'd like to find a way to fix this. I thought of these two:

1. Short the numbers displayed on xAxis like by dividing with 1000 and display each number like  1k, 3k ... etc
2. Skip some ticks, I don't need to see all the ticks if more than 5 ticks.

I prefer the first way [the k shorter] but I'm open to any solution that can make the graph looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the ticks by giving fix intervals like 1k 3k 5k.Here is a piece of code.

```
xaxis:{                     
                  min: 0,
                  max: 24,
                  ticks: ['0','1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'],
                  label:'Hours', 
                  labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
              },
```

Comment: I cannot use predefined ticks values, because I have a large interval of values, from 0 to 10M.